# mod rewrite single url .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite a single URL with the code below?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: Just want to rewrite /home.php to /home - I do not want to rewrite all .php urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex pattern to make it target only `home.php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(home)\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(home)/?$ $1.php [L]
```